# Azure DevOps incremental build / custom Build.SourcesDirectory

Tags: azure-devops

I currently have a setup in Azure DevOps where I have a separate build configuration and a build agent for every branch I need to build to be able to do incremental builds. And then if a new feature branch comes, someone needs again to copy an existing build definition for that and change variables, use another build agent etc, and I'd like to get rid of that. I could of course do clean builds every time, but that takes ~3 hours instead of ~10 minutes incremental.

As far as I have been able to figure out, it's not really possible to do this in DevOps because I can't change the Build.SourcesDirectory -- if I could do that, then my files would be in a separate folder, and incremental builds would work. But no matter what I try, DevOps just overwrites that with the default value.

Is my only option to change my build scripts so that all intermediate files like .obj, .lib etc. are placed to a completely different place? That is possible in theory at least, would be quite a big task for me. Is there nothing that Azure DevOps provides to solve this?